# Install python packages on the same network

Tags: 20.04, python

**The Scenario:**

I have two computers connected to the same network.

On the second computer, I have a python package. I want to install this package on my project through my first computer using of `pip` or another way?

Is it possible?

The operating system of both computers is **Ubuntu**.

Comment: You install it he same way you did the first time? Why would the computers being on the same LAN have to do with anything?

Comment: Probably OP wants to copy the files needed for installation instead of downloading them once again.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi absolutely yes